# aggregate ‘QSqlQuery testQuery’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: sql, qt4, incomplete-type

I'm sure this must be something simple, but I can't quite work out what's up here...

I'm trying to create a QSqlQuery, and the compiler is giving me this:

`error: aggregate ‘QSqlQuery testQuery’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined`

This code is in my mainWindow class:

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    QString filename;
    filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save to SQL Database"),
                                            "~/temp",
                                            tr("Files (*.fdb)"));
    QSqlDatabase testDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    testDatabase.setDatabaseName(filename);

    //this line won't compile:
    QSqlQuery testQuery;

    testDatabase.close();
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::database().connectionName());
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: What are your includes? Seems something's missing, like #include <QSqlQuery> maybe?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I thought that, but I'm including both `#include <QSqlDatabase>` and
`#include <QSqlError>`. Will try QSqlQuery...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Fixed it! Turns out it was QSqlQuery. Have added `#include <QSqlQuery>` and we're compiled. Was working my way through the Qt Sql Programming section in the Reference Documentation and nowhere does it mention QSqlQuery.h!
Fancy adding your solution as an answer?

Comment: Ok, added it as an answer instead :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message indicates that the type SqlQuery is not completely defined. QSqlQuery is defined in

```
#include <QSqlQuery>
```

Include that and things should compile ok.